# Show that Magnetic vector potential is not a physical measureable

Tags: quantum-field-theory

How can we show that Magnetic vector potential $\vec{A}$ is not a physical measureable, even though we know that it causes the geometric phase to occur in the wavefunction $\psi$ in the Ahranov-Bohm effect. Can someone show this mathematically?

In general how do we tell that a physical quantity is a measureable or not?

Comment: My naive answer would be that the equations of motion (Maxwells equations) are gauge invariant under the standard gauge transformation of A. Thus the A field cannot be measuable since a mere redefinition of it results in the same dynamical equations.

Comment: Can we associate the magnetic vector potential to some operator (matrix form) and then show that the operator is not Hermitian?

Comment: Unfortunately i dont know enough to give an insightful answer to that question. Although, expressing the vector potential as an operator sounds unusual to me. However, from memory, in four dimensions a four-vector is hodge dual to some rank x tensor, i cant remember what x is right now though. But i don't think this is what ypu are looking for anyway.

Comment: How do we decide in quantum mechanics that if we can associate an operator (matrix form) to any physical quantity or not?

Comment: To all physical observables there correaponds a Hermitian operator. The converse isn't true though, that is, given a Hermitian operator it doesn't necessarily correspond to a physical observable.

Comment: You should read the wikipedia article on "canonical quantization". It's good intro to what i think you may be looking for.

Comment: Quick comment : Vector potential ($\vec{A}$) is not a physically measureable quantity as it is gauge dependent (nevertheless magnetic field $\vec{B}=\vec{\nabla} X\vec{A}$ is gauge independent). Note, although specific $\vec{A}$ is used in description of Ahranov-Bohm interferometer, the final expression for intensity turns out to be independent of a specific gauge, it only depends on $\oint \vec{A} .d\vec{l} = \iint_{S}\vec{B}.d\vec{a}$.